# What does $2|x_1=u$ mean here?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, notation

In the Wikipedia article

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime

under the section

"Connection with other equations"

I came across the equation $$2|x_1=u$$ The explanation seems to indicate that $2|x_1$ is the valuation of the lowest solution with respect to $2$.

> Did I understand this correctly ?

Comment: The notation $2{\mid}x_1$ means $x_1$ is even. The notation $2{\mid}x_1=u$ is a sloppy concatenation of $2{\mid}x_1$ and $x_1=u$.

Comment: Here's a link to the referenced article: https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022314X03002233/1-s2.0-S0022314X03002233-main.pdf?_tid=37eebcc5-5606-431b-956d-c7c17907b99c&acdnat=1523449730_7ce74d5499ad058d5082ddebc2237228

Comment: @quasi Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It means that $2$ divides $x_1$ (which is what $2 \mid x_1$ means) and that $x_1 = u$. This is not a common notation.

*Note to others checking later: I've edited the wikipedia article to not have this notation anymore.*

Comment: Thanks for the wikipedia fix, and for telling us about it.

Comment: "the lower of the two solutions". Does that mean that there cannot be more than two distinct $x$ such that the equation has a solution ?